# break a forEach with angularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, loops

I need some help. I have 2 loops to traverse two lists of records . The thing is that at some point should put a break or something, because the last loop crushes the value I'm looking for.

This is my code

```
  for (var i in $scope.users) { 
                for (var j in $scope.states) {
                    if ($scope.users[i].id === $scope.states[j].user) {
                        if ($scope.states[j].estado === 'totallyBussy') {
                            $scope.users[i].estado= 'Not available';


                        } else if ($scope.states[j].estado === 'partlyBussy') {
                            $scope.users[i].estado= 'Maybe available';

                        } 
                    }  
                    else {
                             $scope.users[i].estado= 'Available';
                        }                    
                }  

            }
```

Where user 4 and user 5 should be 'Maybe available' and 'Not available', but with this code, I'm getting 'Available for user 0, 1, 2, 3, and the last one. And the last one is crushes with else.

I hope I explained well.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `break` keyword, which will end the loop when executed.

One side note: **you don't want to use** `for (var i in array) {}` since you may iterate through Array properties (and have `i` take unexpected values).
I updated your code with a more reliable iteration.

```
for (var i = 0, il = $scope.users.length; i < il; i++) {
    var user = $scope.users[i];
  for (var j = 0, jl = $scope.states.length; j < jl; j ++) {
    var state = $scope.states[j];

    if (user.id === state.user) {

      if (state.estado === 'totallyBussy') {
        user.estado = 'Not available';
      } else if (state.estado === 'partlyBussy') {
        user.estado = 'Maybe available';
      }
      // Go to the next user (break the "states" loop)
      break;

    } else {
      user.estado = 'Available';
    }
  }

}
```

**EDIT**: If `$scope.users` and `$scope.states` are not Arrays but actually Objects (which would seem strange to me but anyway), you can keep `for (var i in object) {}` but you have to add a check: `if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {}` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a flag which will become true when you got your desired value.

something like

```
                var gotValue = false;

               for (var i in $scope.users) { 
               if(!gotValue)
                 {
                for (var j in $scope.states) {
                    if ($scope.users[i].id === $scope.states[j].user) {
                        if ($scope.states[j].estado === 'totallyBussy') {
                            $scope.users[i].estado= 'Not available';
               gotValue = true;


                        } else if ($scope.states[j].estado === 'partlyBussy') {
                            $scope.users[i].estado= 'Maybe available';
               gotValue = true;

                        } 
                    }  
                    else {
                             $scope.users[i].estado= 'Available';
                gotValue = true;
                        }                    
                }  

}

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS, there is no break for loops,etc., so one has to go with logic manually.

A similar case has been demonstrated [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/3yb0k8k3/).

Here, I have created a variable `f`, which has been set to `false` initially. On `forEach` loop, based on a condition, it is made to `true`, further which it works as `break`.

Please find the code below:

HTML:

```
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test"></div>
```

JS:

```
  var app = angular.module('app',[]);

  app.controller ('test', function ($scope){
      var f = false;
      angular.forEach([1,2,3,4,5], function(v,k){
          if(k > 2){
             f = true;
          }
          if(!f) {
            document.write('value = ' + v + ' <br>');
          }
     });
  });
```